# Why is this datastore querying by key returning None?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, gql

1) When I perform this query:

```
contract_record = Contract(book_number = 42, initial_page = 420, final_page = 442)
contract_record.put()
contract_key = contract_record.key()
contract = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract WHERE __key__ = KEY('Contract', '$[contract_key]')").get()
```

The result is None. Why?

2) How to make this query not by the key, but the key_id?
(something like this:

```
contract_id = contract_record.key().id()
contract = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Contract WHERE __key__ = KEY('Contract', '$[contract_id]')").get()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `'$[contract_key]'` supposed to be? Are you trying to do some sort of string substitution here? That really isn't how it works. Perhaps you mean to use the `%s` operator?

In any case, I don't really understand why you insist on doing queries via GQL. The way to get an object by its key is directly with `get`:

```
contract = db.get(contract_key)
```

and for the key ID:

```
contract = Contract.get_by_id(id)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel, I think only now I fully understand your previous advice (on how to get an datastore object by its key). Really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but you could try this:

```
contract_record = Contract(book_number = 42, initial_page = 420, final_page = 442)
contract_record.put()
contract_key = contract_record.key()
contract = db.get(contract_key)
```